# Responsive table with different size column and row names

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I am trying to create a matrix that looks like this:

[image]

What is bugging me off is how to make the column and row names responsive with the grid in the middle. So far I have this code: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Premitium/nnnau6qu/2/)

```
 t t t t
 e e e e
 x x x x
 t t t t
 0 0 0 0 text
 0 0 0 0 text
 0 0 0 0 text
 0 0 0 0 text
```

I tried making the text, part of the matrix but the different size of the elements cracks the responsiveness for smaller screens. Currently when the vertical text is not part of the matrix it looks almost alright, but the horizontal text is not.

I am looking for some advice on how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

What's with

```
 Text
   Text
     Text
       Text
 0 0 0 0 text
 0 0 0 0 text
 0 0 0 0 text
 0 0 0 0 text
```

*If it doesn't fit side by side, put them on top of each other.*

You have to look, whether it fits your requirements. (I would suggest a smaller font size and smaller line height for the column headings then)

Comment: It design dependent.